# "Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null" being returned when username is entered wrong

Tags: php, authentication, null, notice

I am trying to create a login page, and everything works as expected, except for when a wrong username is entered, I get the error `Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null` for the line `if ($_POST['username'] != $row['username']) {` in the below code, and I do not understand enough to fix it, as I am still pretty new to this. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Any advice on proper ways to write and/or execute my code is welcome as well, thank you.

````
session_start();

$DATABASE_HOST = "localhost";
$DATABASE_USER = "root";
$DATABASE_PASSWORD = "";
$DATABASE_NAME = "tasktracker";

$link = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASSWORD, $DATABASE_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

    exit("Failed to connect to database: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}

//Server side form validation

if ($_POST) {

    if (!$_POST['username']) {

        $error .= "A username is required!<br>";

    }

    if (!$_POST['password']) {

        $error .= "A password is required!<br>";

    }

    if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 8) {

        $error .= "Your password must be greater than 8 characters!<br>";

    }

    if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 30) {

        $error .= "Your password must be less than 30 characters!<br>";

    }

if ($error != "") {

    $error = '<div class=""><p><strong>There were issues(s) in your form:</strong></p>' . $error . '</div>';

    echo $error;

    

} else {

//Log user in

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username'])."' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($_POST['username'] != $row['username']) {

        $error = "That username is incorrect.";

    } else if (md5(md5($row['id']).$_POST['password']) != $row['password']) {

        $error = "That password is incorrect.";

    } else {

        echo 1;

    }

    if ($error != "") {

        $error = '<div class=""><p><strong>There were issues(s) in your form:</strong></p>' . $error . '</div>';

        echo $error;

    } else {

        exit();

    }

}

}```
````

Comment: There are now rows so `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns `null`. This means `password` indice doesn't exist on `$row` "array". Check if you have results before your other checks. The `$_POST['username'] != $row['username']` check isn't needed, your SQL does that check already. You shouldn't use `md5` for hashing, and I'm not sure about the salting approach either. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php are the preffered methods.

Comment: **Warning**:You passwords are not safe. php has built in password [hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php). A [tutorial](https://alexwebdevelop.com/php-password-hashing/).

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I have switched my code to now using the ```password_hash``` function

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
if ($_POST['username'] != $row['username']) {

    $error = "That username is incorrect.";

}
```

by

```
if (!$result) {

    $error = "That username is incorrect.";

}
```

because if `$result` is false or has 0 items then no user was found with this username

Comment: I tried this, and my code now shows this ```if (!$result) {

  $error = "That username is incorrect.";

 } else if (!password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password'])) {

  $error = "That password is incorrect.";

 } else {

  echo 1;

 }``` and now, it no longer tells me that the username is wrong, instead it says the password is wrong and I get the same notice but instead on the line ```else if (!password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']))```

Comment: are you did a print of $row for check the containt ?